# Enable OEM unlocking and unlock bootloader on an HTC device

Tags: root-access, htc-desire, bootloader-lock

Recently I bought HTC Desire 530 phone from the Facebook Marketplace and have been tricked with a demo phone. It's a new phone, not even a scratch, but i demo keeps popping up every 30 seconds. I want to root it and install a fresh stock ROM but can't unlock the bootloader.

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Click images for larger variants</sup>

I followed several tutorials on YouTube and XDA but couldn't get it working.

How to OEM unlock and unlock the bootloader for this device?

Answer (score 0):

[You need to sign up as a developer](https://www.htcdev.com/) to unlock an HTC bootloader.

There's a full set of instructions on [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/desire-530/help/htc-desire-530-root-s-off-t3450563)

> 1) Visit htcdev.com and unlock your bootloader
>   -sign up as a dev, activate your email, and follow the steps
>
> 2) Download twrp from the app store. You won’t be able to run it yet but
>   you still need it
>
> 3) Put the supersu zip file from your computer into
>   your download folder of your phone
>
> 4) Get fastboot & adb running on
>   your computer.
>
> - open cmd prompt
> - navigate to the fastboot/adb folder in your cmd prompt
> - with your phone plugged into your computer type “adb devices”
> - if it returns your device good
> - now in cmd type “adb reboot downloader” (you can also do this by powering off your phone then turning your phone on by holding the down
>     volume button and the power button at the same time.
> - once you are in the downloader type “fastboot devices” in cmd
> - if this returns your device good
> - DO NOT GO ANY FURTHER TILL THIS IS WORKING!!! 4)Once your phone is in the rebooted downloader screen type “fastboot flash recovery
>     ”
> - make sure you are on the downloader page and not the bootloader page
> - this should end in .img
> - this is a second boot screen for your phone. The first time I did this recovery wasn’t working because I was trying to fastboot on the
>     bootloader page.
>
> 5) Now boot into recovery mode by navigating to it on
>   your phone or using the cmd “adb reboot recovery”
>   - Once you are here you will see the twrp screen
>
> 6a) The way I did it is going into the twrp recovery boot and going to install and choosing
>   the supersu.zip file I moved to my phone in step 3. After it is done
>   reboot your phone and now you are rooted.
>
> 6b) The other way is to go
>   to advanced in twrp and enable sideload
>   - now in cmd type “adb sideload ”
>
> 7) If you need to turn S-OFF install sunshine on your phone and it will do it.
>   - You need to have your phone rooted first to turn your S-OFF with sunshine

Comment: I can't unlock the bootloader because OEM isn't unlocked.

Comment: That's why you go sign up at htcdev.com as a developer. They'll give you the code to OEM unlock so you can unlock the bootloader.